# How to extract text from webcam image

Tags: python, string, webcam, python-tesseract

I am trying to extract text from the image taken by webcam. My code is below :

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string
import cv2
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
time.sleep(3)
ret, frame = cap.read()
if ret != True:
    raise ValueError("Can't read frame")

cv2.imwrite('img2.png', frame)
cv2.imshow("img1", frame)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


img = Image.open('img2.png')
text = image_to_string(img, lang='eng')
print(text)
```

[image]

I could extract text from screen shot image and now trying same thing in terms of webcam.
I just attempted to take photo with webcam and the download image taken by webcam and used `image_to_string()` to extract text from that image.

But it does not return any text even though the image is correctly taken.
How should I edit this ?
Otherwise, if you have any other good idea, I would like to know.

Comment: Good idea: **take a better picture**. There's a lot of text going on on the back of the sheet you used to write the "A" letter and that could cause problems to the `image_to_string` algorithm

Comment: Either that or you need to modify the image in order to make the letter more visible